# how to remove duplicate results

Tags: sql, postgresql

given the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS companies (
  id serial,
  name text NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars (
  id serial,
  make text NOT NULL,
  year integer NOT NULL,
  company_id INTEGER REFERENCES companies(id),

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO companies (id, name) VALUES
  (1, 'toyota'),
  (2, 'chevy');

INSERT INTO cars (make, year, company_id) VALUES
  ('silverado', 1995, 2),
  ('malibu', 1999, 2),
  ('tacoma', 2017, 1),
  ('custom truck', 2010, null),
  ('van custom', 2005, null);
```

how do i select the rows for cars, only showing the newest car for a given company?

e.g.

```
select make, companies.name as model, year from cars 
left join companies
on companies.id = cars.company_id
order by make;
```

outputs

```
     make     | model  | year 
--------------+--------+------
 custom truck |        | 2010
 malibu       | chevy  | 1999
 silverado    | chevy  | 1995
 tacoma       | toyota | 2017
 van custom   |        | 2005
```

but i only want to show the newest "chevy", e.g.

```
     make     | model  | year 
--------------+--------+------
 custom truck |        | 2010
 malibu       | chevy  | 1999
 tacoma       | toyota | 2017
 van custom   |        | 2005
```

and still be able to sort by "make", and to show cars without a null company_id.

fiddle link:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Vh1sFXvEvnbnUJsCYhCHf/0

Comment: Your `cars` table doesn't have `model` but that is in your result set.

Comment: i'm using `model` as an alias for `companies.name` in the example select query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL can be done based on Set Math (discrete math). So, you want the set of all cars minus the set of cars whose years a less than the maximum year for a given company id.

The set of all cars:

```
select * from cars
```

The set of all cars whose year is less than the maximum year for a given company id:

```
select a.id from cars a, cars b where a.company_id = b.company_id  and a.year < b.year
```

One set minus the other:

```
select * from cars where id not in (select a.id from cars a, cars b where a.company_id = b.company_id  and a.year < b.year)
```

Result which includes the null company_ids because they are excluded from the id comparison:

```
     make     | model  | year 
--------------+--------+------
 custom truck |        | 2010
 malibu       | chevy  | 1999
 tacoma       | toyota | 2017
 van custom   |        | 2005
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of common table expressions and row_number function, we can get the desired output and below is the query that gives the desired output.

```
     WITH temp AS 
    (SELECT 
        make
        , companies.name AS model
        , year
        , row_number() over(PARTITION BY coalesce(companies.name, make) ORDER BY year desc) as rnk
    FROM   
       cars
    left join 
       companies
    ON 
       companies.id = cars.company_id
    )
    SELECT 
       make
       , model
       , year
    FROM
       temp
    WHERE
       rnk = 1
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, this is best done using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (co.id) ca.*, co.name as model
from cars ca left join
     companies co
     on ca.company_id = co.id
order by co.id, ca.year desc;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is very handy Postgres syntax.  It keeps one row for each combination in parentheses.  The specific row is determined by the `ORDER BY` clause.

However, you have a twist, because `co.id` can be `null`.  In that case, you seem to want to keep all the cars with no company.

So:

```
select distinct on (co.id, case when co.id is null then ca.id end) ca.*, co.name
from cars ca left join
     companies co
     on ca.company_id = co.id
order by co.id, case when co.id is null then ca.id end, ca.year desc;
```

Or perhaps more simply using `union all`:

```
-- get the ones with a company
select distinct on (co.id) ca.*, co.name
from cars ca join
     companies co
     on ca.company_id = co.id
union all
-- get the ones with no company
select ca.*, null
from cars ca
where ca.company_id is null
order by year desc;
```

In other databases, this would typically be done using `row_number()`:

```
select ca.*
from (select ca.*, co.name as model,
             row_number() over (partition by co.id,
                                             case when co.id is null then ca.id end
                                order by year desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from cars ca left join
           companies co
           on ca.company_id = co.id
     ) ca
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: can the DISTINCT ON solution be sorted by make or year?

Comment: @schpet . . . `DISTINCT ON` uses the `ORDER BY` to define the rows in the result set.  If you want a different final ordering, the you need a subquery/CTE and an additional `ORDER BY`.